# Can a scala self-type be satisfied via delegation?

Tags: scala, delegation, implicits, self-type

Suppose I have (and this is rather contrived)

```
trait DbConnection {
  val dbName: String
  val dbHost: String
}

class Query {
  self: DbConnection =>

  def doQuery(sql: String) {
    // connect using dbName, dbHost
    // perform query
  }
}

class HasADbConnection(override val dbName: String, 
                       override val dbHost: String) extends DbConnection {
  self =>

  def doSomething() {
    doSomethingElseFirst()
  }

  def doSomethingElseFirst() = {
    val query = new Query() with DbConnection {
      override val dbName = self.dbName
      override val dbHost = self.dbHost
    }
    query.doQuery("")
  }
}
```

Is there a way to avoid the redundant "override val dbName = self.dbName, override val dbHost = self.dbHost" in the new Query() creation, and instead indicate that the new Query object should inherit from / delegate to the HasADbConnection instance for these fields?

I realize it may be more appropriate for Query to take a DbConnection as a constructor argument.  I'm interested though in other ways of satisfying the Query self-type.  Perhaps there is no way of propagating the HasADbconnection fields onto the new Query instance, which is a completely valid answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to do, but this seems like a possible match to your intent:

```
trait C extends B {
    def myA = new A() with C {  // Note that this could be "with B" rather than "with C" and it would still work.
        val name: String = C.this.name // explicit type not actually required - String type can be inferred.
    }
}
```

then, for example:

```
scala> val myC = new C() { val name = "myC-name" }
myC: C = $anon$1@7f830771

scala> val anA = myC.myA
anA: A with C = C$$anon$1@249c38d5

scala> val aName = anA.name
aName: String = myC-name
```

Hopefully that can at least help guide your eventual solution. Might be able to give further help if you clarify what you want to do (or why you want to do it) further.

**EDIT** - after update to question:

I suggest you may be thinking about this the wrong way. I would not like tying the Query class down to knowing how to forge a connection. Rather, either pass a ready-made connection as a parameter to your call that uses the connection, or (as shown below) set up the Query class to supply a function from a connection to a result, then call that function using a connection established elsewhere.

Here is a how I would think about solving this (note that this example doesn't create an actual DB connection per se, I just take your DbConnection type at face value - really you have actually defined a 'DbConnConfig' type):

```
trait DbConnection {
  val dbName: String
  val dbHost: String
}


class Query(sql: String) {
  def doQuery: DbConnection => String = { conn: DbConnection =>
    // No need here to know how to: connect using dbName, dbHost
    // perform query, using provided connection:
    s"${conn.dbName}-${sql}-${conn.dbHost}" // <- Dummy implementation only here, so you can, for example, try it out in the REPL.
  }
}


class HasADbConnection(override val dbName: String,
                       override val dbHost: String) extends DbConnection {

  // You can create your actual connection here...
  val conn = makeConnection

  def doSomething(query: Query) = {
    // ... or here, according to your program's needs.
    val conn = makeConnection
    query.doQuery(conn)
  }

  def makeConnection = this // Not a real implementation, just a quick cheat for this example.
}
```

In reality, doQuery (which could be named better) should have a type of `DbConnection => ResultSet` or similar. Example usage:

```
scala> val hasConn = new HasADbConnection("myDb", "myHost")
hasConn: HasADbConnection = HasADbConnection@6c1e5d2f

scala> hasConn.doSomething(new Query("@"))
res2: String = myDb-@-myHost
```